# Disappearing cola in a hot car

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, evaporation, explosions

I unadvisably left an unopened can of cola in my car on a very hot, sunny day. The top blew off and when i recovered the can it was clean and dry inside. Except for a few sticky droplets on the windshield all of the cola was gone and left no evidence of its passage. Nothing in the car was sticky or wet except a few tiny spots on the windshield.

What happened to the cola? I can imagine the liquid subliming but that should leave the sugar. Did it all atomize and now is covering the interior with an imperceptibly thin layer that can't generally be seen or felt? Somebody please help me figure this out, it's been puzzling me for almost 2 years.

Comment: Repeat the experiment many, many times? With real coke, real Pepsi, RC,….

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos I can testify that the same thing happens with real Pepsi :-)

Answer (score 1):

The volatile components of the cola (basically water) evaporate. The non volatile components (e.g. sugar) do not. When the can burst open some liquid drops splashed in the windshield but most of the liquid likely stayed in the can and slowly evaporated because of the high temperature. You will find the sugar *inside* the can, probably as a thin coating on the bottom and walls of the can.